# Open XML SDK: Вычисление абсолютной координаты X фигуры, находящейся в групповой фигуре

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

Мне необходимо получить абсолютную координату *X* фигуры `(Freeform 39)`, которая находиться в групповой фигуре *(Group 37)*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю вычисления таким образом

```
4637017 (GroupShape X) + 5863712 (target ChildShape) = 10500729
```

но вычисление не верное, т.к. после того как я разместил отдельную фигуру с такой координатой *X* (10500729), то увидел разницу.

**Как правильно вычислить абсолютную координату *X* фигуры из групповой фигуры?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибку, вывел следующую формула для нахождения абсолютных координат дочернего элемента на слайде:

**absChildShapeOffset,x(y) =  childShapeOffset,x(y) + groupShapeOffset,x(y) - childShapeOffset,x(y)**